# How can I search and return the values and pass it to the method from spock table

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

Currently implementing GEB,Spock,Groovy. I come across the scenario like

There is a set of data's in the spock table. I have to pass the modulename as a parameter, Search from the spock table then return two values user id and password.  Below code is skeleton code

My question is how to search module name based on parameter?
How to return two data's ?

```
Class Password_Collection extends Specification {

def "Secure password for search and Data Driven"(String ModuleName) {

   expect:
           // Search based on modulename in where
           // pick the values and return the picked data


            where:
            Module              | User_Name     | Pass_word
            login_Pass          | cqauthor1     | SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ =
            AuthorPageTest_Pass | cqauthor2     | DOIaRTd35f3y4De =
            PublisherPage_pass  | cqaauthor3    | iFK95JKasdfdO5 ==

}
        }
```

If you provide the code it would be great help to learn and imeplement.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to search the table yourself or pick that data. Spock will do that automatically for you

In the **expect:** block just write your unit test that uses *Module*, *User_Name* and *Pass_word*. Spock will automatically run the test 3 times (as many as the rows of the table) passing each row in turn to your test.

Remove the argument *ModuleName* from the test method. It is not needed.

I suggest you read the Spock documentation on Data Driven tests a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

```
class YourSpec extends Specification {
    def "Secure password for search and Data Driven"(Module, User_Name, Pass_Word) {
        expect:
        classUnderTest.getUserNameForModule(Module) == User_Name
        classUnderTest.getPasswordForModule(Module) == Pass_Word

        where:
        Module              | User_Name     | Pass_word
        login_Pass          | cqauthor1     | SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ =
        AuthorPageTest_Pass | cqauthor2     | DOIaRTd35f3y4De =
        PublisherPage_pass  | cqaauthor3    | iFK95JKasdfdO5 ==

    }
}
```

What Spock will do is run your test one time for each row in the data table from the "where" block, passing Module, User_Name, Pass_Word as parameters and assert your expectations in the "expect" block.

Please refer to [Spock Data Driven Testing](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html) documentation for more details.

Comment: Scenario is : Passing the module name, it will search in the where block once it matches, user_name and pass_word should be captured and return to another method/class password will be decrypted and userid and password will send it to another module as credential. But in the code it returns true or pass.

Comment: Please correct me the below code based on above scenario.           class PasswordCollection extends Specification {

   
        def "Secure password for Data Driven"(String keyword) {
            expect:
            if(keyword ==Module )
            return encryptPassPass_word

           
        where:
        Module              | User_Name     | Pass_word