# How to pick the particular row value from spock table

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

I have to Store multiple data's in the spock table . When ever required i have to pass the data through parameter value, according to that it should search in the spock table, pick corresponding data. Please see the code and correct it. 
It would be very much helpful to me to implement my project.

```
 def passW = "Publisher"
 def "getPassword" (passW) {

expect:

     if (secureKeyword == passW ) {

        println "Result is " + encryptPass
       }

     where:
     secureKeyword || encryptPass
     "Author"      || "aW50ZWxAMTIzNCE="
     "Publisher"   || "tsdwerDhV76wYCf="
 }
```

Result should be : ​tsdwerDhV76wYCf=​

Comment: Think you are confused as to what tests are for. Both should pass, why would you want to run one?

Comment: I dont want to run all the items in the where table.In my application i have to use different credentials for different modules. so i store module name, password. When i pass module name it should pick corresponding password and set it to password column. (Userid will be given directly).

Comment: Again, that's not how unit/integration tests are for.

Comment: tim_yates : Can you give me any other solution to pick data from spock table?

Comment: Maybe some context on what you are trying to test instead of i need to pick this data from a table so please fix the code below?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I search and return the values and pass it to the method from spock table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39763657/how-can-i-search-and-return-the-values-and-pass-it-to-the-method-from-spock-tabl)

Answer (score 0):

You can store module data in the static (or @Shared) collection and filter test input in where section in findAll closure.

```
def static moduleCredentials = ["Author":"aW50ZWxAMTIzNCE=",
                             "Publisher":"tsdwerDhV76wYCf="]

@Unroll
def "Module #module.key login credentials test"(){
        def moduleName = module.key
        def modulePass = module.value
        println(moduleName+":"+modulePass)
        expect:
        assert modulePass

        where:
        module << moduleCredentials.findAll {it.key=="Author"}.entrySet()
    }
```